# HASHBYTES() equivalent in Progress OpenEdge 11.7

Tags: sql, openedge, hashbytes

I use HASHBYTES() with SQL server 2012, is there any equivalent with OpenEdge?

example of working code in SQL 2012

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5',CONCAT(col1, col2)) AS [HashDiff] FROM MyTable
```

example of what i want achive in progress

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServerToProgress,'SELECT HASHBYTES(''MD5'',CONCAT(col1, col2)) AS [HashDiff] FROM pub.myTable')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql

Any clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `MESSAGE-DIGEST` function. Does it work for your needs?

```
FOR EACH myTable:
   myVar = MESSAGE-DIGEST('MD5', myTable.col1 + myTable.col2).
END.
```

Comment: @HuguesGauthier No, I don't know enough details